# Twitter4j Streaming with Geolocation

Tags: twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I am using Twitter4j streaming API. I am using a geolocation constraint to get the tweets only from a specific area. Here is that part of the code:

```
    twitterStream.addListener(listener);
    String[] keywordsArray = { "iphone", "america", "samsung" };
    FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
    filterQuery.track(keywordsArray);
    double[][] locations = { { 40.714623d, -74.006605d },
            { 42.3583d, -71.0603d } };
    filterQuery.locations(locations);
    twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
```

This actually returns me results but almost all the tweets come with geolocation as NULL. One out of 25-30 (or even more)tweets will have a geotag. Can anyone point me to what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, twitter streaming API does not allow searching by both keyword **AND** location. Your code is searching for tweets which either have the keywords:{ "iphone", "america", "samsung" } **OR** belong to the location: { { 40.714623d, -74.006605d },{ 42.3583d, -71.0603d } }.
Hence the tweets that you are getting which have a geo tag are the ones which belong to the given location while others are due to the given keywords.